# How to append the lines of a file to the end of the lines of other file?

Tags: text-processing

File #1:

```
I have foofoo
You have foobar
she/he has foo
```

File #2:

```
bar
foobar
barfoo
```

Final:

```
I have foofoobar
You have foobarfoobar
she/he has foobarfoo
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With POSIX [paste](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html):

```
paste -d'\0' file1 file2 > new_file
```

With [paste from GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils#paste-invocation), you can use `-d ''`.

Comment: @cuonglm wow, so it is! Sorry, I thought I had checked with `od -c` but apparently I hadn't. Feel free to revert my edit with my apologies.

Comment: @tachomi I had no idea what I was talking about. Please ignore my previous comments. It turns out that `-d'\0'` and `-d ''` are equivalent (at least on Linux). Knowing cuonglm, the `-d'\0'` is likely to be more portable and that's why he chose it.

Answer (score 3):

cuonglm clearly has the best answer. Two alternatives:

1. shell (`bash`, `zsh`, `ksh` variants, `mksh`)

   ```
   while read -u3 a; read -u4 b; do echo "$a$b"; done 3<file1 4<file2 > result
   ```
2. awk

   ```
   awk '{a[FNR] = a[FNR] $0};END {for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) print a[i]}' file1 file2 > result
   ```